# VBA select drop down menu value from HKEX website

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scraping table from below website. there's a drop down list on the left part of the website and I want to select and click "Professional" in the type section. Below is my VBA code. I have no web developing experience and as far as I can do is only find the table I want and select show 100 items

[image]

```
Sub CopyFromHKEXWebsite()
    Dim ie As Object, btnmore As Object, tbl As Object
    Dim cnt As Integer
         
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Debt-Securities?sc_lang=en"
        
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy
        
        .Document.getelementsbyclassname("select_items")(0).setAttribute "style", "display: block"
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Busy  'wait for scriptcode to execute
        .Document.getelementsbyclassname("select_items")(0).Children(2).Click
        
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy
        
        ****'professional
        .Document.getelementsbyid("select2")(0).selectedindex = 1
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Busy  'wait for scriptcode to execute****
                     
        Do
            Set tbl = .Document.getelementsbyclassname("table_debtsecurities")(0)
            Set btnmore = .Document.getelementsbyclassname("loadmore")(0)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
            
        Loop While tbl Is Nothing Or btnmore Is Nothing And cnt < 5 'maximum attempts = 4
        
        Do While btnmore.getattribute("style") = ""
            btnmore.Click
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While .Busy
        Loop
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There's a shortcut for this question, just change website to `https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Debt-Securities?sc_lang=en&type=0` (add "&type=0" behind "sc_lang=en") then the website will automatically convert to "Professional" table, but I want to learn more how it works by using VBA `.click` fuction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is not `GetElementsById` but `GetElementById` (singular `Element` without `s`) because there cannot be multiple elements with the same `ID` (without violating the HTML standard). While for `Name` and `ClassName` there can exist multiple elements it needs to be plural `Elements` with an `s`.

Second you find the the combobox by its `name="select2"` so we need to use `GetElementsByName`

```html
<input type="hidden" name="select2" value="ALL">
```

```
Dim TypeCombo As Object
Set TypeCombo = .document.GetElementsByName("select2")(0)
TypeCombo.Value = "Professional"
```

Then the apply button

```html
<div class="etps_apply_btn">APPLY FILTERS</div>
```

can be found by its `class="etps_apply_btn"` so we use `GetElementsByClassName`

```
Dim ApplyButton As Object
Set ApplyButton = .document.GetElementsByClassName("etps_apply_btn")(0)
    
ApplyButton.Click
```

and apply a click.

Comment: Thank you! The code runs smoothly and does exactly what I intend to do! Very appreciated! BTW if I want to learn more about html or scraping data using vba, do you have any resource recommend? : )

Comment: StackOverflow [tag:web-scraping] including [tag:vba]